# How to access element some element in dictionary

Tags: python, list, numpy, dictionary

I have a huge dictionary in Python. Let's say, 400k element pairs. I know that all keys are different, while all values - are fixed dimension vectors. For further processing I need to create numpy zero vector with shape, identical to shape of all vectors in the dictionary. In order to accomplish this task I run the following code:

```
import numpy as np
for vector in dictionary.values(): break;
accumulator = np.zeros_like(vector);
```

Is there any more elegant way to accomplish the same functionality? I tried to create a list from values and get

```
vector = list(dictionary.values())[0];
```

but this was painfully slow.

For loop works fast and provides expected results, but I see it as dirty hack.

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: This is Python3. I tried your variant with next and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first value out of an iterator you can use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next)

```
vector = next(iter(dictionary.values()))
```

[We need to use `iter` to turn the view object returned by `dict.values()` into an iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects)

Answer (score -1):

That for-loop really looks useless. Wouldn't this do the same

```
vector = dictionary.values()[0]
```

So vector is first item from list dictionary.values() method returns.

--- EDIT ---

And just as duckboycool commented, this works in Python2. But with Python3 you need

```
vector = next(iter(dictionary.values()))
```

as mentioned here in Iain Shelvingtons post.

Thanks for correcting.

Comment: It wouldn't, `dict_values` aren't indexable.

Comment: That works in Python2, but you're right when using Python3.